# Need the user to select / enter quarter to get the desired output in PIG-0.12.0

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am working on the NYSE dataset wherein I have created the following problem statement -

Earnings growth in recent quarters compared with earlier rates of change.
Fetch the data quarter wise and bump it against comparable time frames, for example quarter over quarter and present a report as a performance comparison.

I have created the script as mentioned below -

```
daily = load 'NYSE_daily.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray, date:chararray, open:float, high:float , low:float, close:float, volume:float, adj_close:float);
--describe daily;
qtr1_filter = FILTER daily by date >= '2009-04-01' and date <= '2009-06-30';
qtr1_result = foreach qtr1_filter generate symbol, close-open as change; 
qtr1_grp_stock = group qtr1_result by symbol;
qtr1_stocks = foreach qtr1_grp_stock generate group as symbol, SUM(qtr1_result.change) as change;

qtr2_filter = FILTER daily by date >= '2009-07-01' and date <= '2009-09-30';
qtr2_result = foreach qtr2_filter generate symbol, close-open as change; 
qtr2_grp_stock = group qtr2_result by symbol;
qtr2_stocks = foreach qtr2_grp_stock generate group as symbol, SUM(qtr2_result.change) as change;

qtr_join = JOIN qtr1_stocks by symbol, qtr2_stocks by symbol;
stocks_ord = order qtr_join by qtr2_stocks::change desc;
store stocks_ord into 'earninggrowth';
```

This will work for a couple of quarters however, what I need is to enter / specify the quarters dynamically to get the desired output.

The second thing which I am trying to achieve is Fetch the annual performance data and compare the performance. The time period can be the fiscal year, that is from April 1 till March 31st.

I have been googling however, couldn't find anything which helps you in learning to work with dates dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using macros:

growth.pig:

```
DEFINE findGrowth(data, startDate, endDate) RETURNS stocks {
  filtered = FILTER data by date >= '$startDate' and date <= '$endDate';
  res = foreach filtered generate symbol, close-open as change; 
  grp_stock = group res by symbol;
  $stocks = foreach grp_stock generate group as symbol, SUM(res.change) as change;
};

DEFINE changesBetween(start1, end1, start2, end2) RETURNS void {
  data = load '/path/to/NYSE_daily' using PigStorage() as (exchange:chararray, 
    symbol:chararray, date:chararray, open:float, high:float, 
    low:float,  close:float, volume:float, adj_close:float);  
  stocks1 = findGrowth(data, '$start1', '$end1');
  stocks2 = findGrowth(data, '$start2', '$end2');
  joined = JOIN stocks1 by symbol, stocks2 by symbol;
  ord = order joined by stocks2::change desc;
  store joined into 'changes_$start1-$end2';
};

changesBetween('$startDate1', '$endDate1', '$startDate2', '$endDate2');
```

Then create a shell script
findChanges.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage ./findChanges.sh [startDate1 endDate1 startDate2 endDate2]
pig -f growth.pig -param startDate1="$1" -param endDate1="$2" \
                  -param startDate2="$3" -param endDate2="$4"
```

So that you'll end up having:

```
./findChanges.sh 2009-04-01 2009-06-30 2009-07-01 2009-09-30
```

This will create the result under *'changes_2009-04-01-2009-09-30'*

Comment: Thanks for the solution however, can you suggest wherein I only have to just pass two parameters i.e. start of qtr and end of qtr instead of passing 4 as suggested by you lets say I want results for 3 quarters start date 2009-04-01 and end date 2009-12-31 can we acheive it for the given set of data. if you wish I can upload the data and send it across to you.

Comment: The code above applies the quarters dynamically i.e takes them from command line. To implement the further requirement you just mentioned, I'd combine the code above code with the embedded python feature http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/cont.html#embed-python where you can apply control flow (e.g: loops). Btw. end date is not really necessary if you have the start date and the number of quarters.

Comment: Ok got it. This will resolve the yearly comparison problem as well.